# Does $\omega(1)$ mean non-constant?

Tags: asymptotics

Let's say I have a discrete structure of size $n$, and some characteristic $a$ of that structure for which it holds that $a= \omega(1)$.

Is this equivalent to say  that $a$ can not be a constant but it has some dependence on $n$?

Comment: First write down the definition of $\omega(1)$.  Then look for a "characteristic" not satisfying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n)=\omega(g(n))$ means that 
$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\infty
$. $\omega(1)$ means that $f(n)$ is asymptotically larger than constant, i.e. $f(n)=\log n$ or $f(n)= n$